# no match for ‘operator[]' when trying to simplify code into range-based for-loop for move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to reduce and simplify the size of my code, but encountered this error:

```
BucketSort.cpp: In member function ‘void BucketSort::sort(unsigned int)’:
BucketSort.cpp:118:34: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned int> [10]’ and ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’)
         std::move(std::begin(vecs[i]), std::end(vecs[i]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
                                  ^
BucketSort.cpp:118:53: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned int> [10]’ and ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’)
         std::move(std::begin(vecs[i]), std::end(vecs[i]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
                                                     ^
make: *** [BucketSort.o] Error 1
Ivans-MacBook-Pro:CS6771A5-ParallelBucketSort ivanteong$
```

I'm trying to simplify from:

```
numbersToSort = std::move(vecs[0]); // bucket containing 0 (handle case where there is a number that is 0)
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[1]), std::end(vecs[1]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[2]), std::end(vecs[2]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[3]), std::end(vecs[3]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[4]), std::end(vecs[4]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[5]), std::end(vecs[5]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[6]), std::end(vecs[6]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[7]), std::end(vecs[7]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[8]), std::end(vecs[8]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
    std::move(std::begin(vecs[9]), std::end(vecs[9]), std::back_inserter(numbersToSort));
```

to a range-based for-loop:

```
for (auto i : vecs) {
    std::move(
        std::begin(vecs[i]),
        std::end(vecs[i]),
        std::back_inserter(numbersToSort)
    );
}
```

Declarations in my .h file are:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> numbersToSort;
std::vector<unsigned int> vecs[10] = {
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>(),
    std::vector<unsigned int>()
};
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is more:

```
for (auto& vec : vecs) {
    std::move(
        std::begin(vec),
        std::end(vec),
        std::back_inserter(numbersToSort)
    );
}
```

The range-based for-loop doesn't expand an index but a true variable copying, or, using `auto&` instead of `auto`, referencing the content of the given container.